# how can i group radio buttons that are in different div tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have radio buttons placed in different `div`. How can I make only one of these selectable?

```html
<div><input type="radio" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" /></div>
```

Comment: Give same name to all those inputs.

Comment: The duplicate answer ISN'T  a duplicate answer. This should be reopened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`radio` inputs are grouped by the `name` attribute, which is required to maintain HTML validity. It also makes retrieving the selected value possible on the server side.

```html
<div><input type="radio" name="foo" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="foo" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="foo" /></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="foo" /></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

add an attribute `name="myRadio"` for each radio.

Answer (score 2):

Use the same `name` attribute with different `value` for those radio buttons.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can we keep same value for radio buttons? we should have same name for `radio` buttons and each radio button should have different value so that it can be used at server side. For example two radio buttons with same name `sex` but diff values as `male` and `female` so that we can get value of that radio button using name `sex` at the server side..

Comment: You're correct. I misread your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in different form tag

```
<div><form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Group 1 Option 1</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">Group 1 Option 2</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">Group 1 Option 3</label>
</fieldset>
</form>
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Group 2 Option 1</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">Group 2 Option 2</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">Group 2 Option 3</label>
</fieldset>
</form>
```